# NAOqi: Port NAO code from 2.1 to 2.8

Tags: nao-robot

NAOqi 2.8 has no DCM anymore. How to replace it, e.g., in the following code?

```
proxy = new AL::DCMProxy(pBroker); // does not work anymore
proxy->createAlias(someAliasDeclaration);
proxy->setAlias(someValuesForAlias);
proxy->getGenericProxy()->getModule()->atPreProcess(&someFunction);
proxy->getGenericProxy()->getModule()->atPostProcess(&someOtherFunction);
```

I did not find any hints in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think in NAOqi 2.8 you won't be able to bypass NAOqi, so the only possibility will be to use the ALMotion functions. see http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/motion/almotion-api.html

Comment: Is it possible to set the 25 joint angles and stiffnesses 100 times per second, synchronously with the ALMotion execution cycle? All RoboCup teams use their own walk, which requires precise timing. The methods in the ALMotion API are asynchronous, which does not sound as if they were made for real-time control.
Does ALMotion support `atPreProcess` and `atPostProcess` in terms of a 100Hz real-time control?

Comment: I doubt that any RoboCup team will be satisfied with 41.7Hz (that's worse than with the old 2008 NAO V2). This makes the robot basically unusable for the purpose it was sold for. There must be an interface to access LoLA directly.